# Slicing NumPy 3d array

Tags: numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am learning NumPy.  I created 3d array like this:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]])
a 

a
# array([[[1, 2],
#         [3, 4]],
#        [[5, 6],
#         [7, 8]]])
```

I am trying to access values 3 to 6 as under:

```
a[0,1] # array([3, 4])
a[1,0] # array([5, 6])

a[0,1][1,0] # IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Is this possible through one-liner slice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]])

tmp = a.flatten()
tmp[2:6]
```